# Font.charset being changed to ANSI when loading files

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Whenever we (everyone in the office) loads a dfm file, the Font.charset for all the elements in that file change.

```
Font.charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
```

becomes

```
Font.charset = ANSI_CHARSET
```

this causes a lot of headaches when trying to find the change we actually made in the file. Is there a setting somewhere we can change to stop this?

Comment: Why do you not generally leave the value ANSI_CHARSET? As long as you use common system fonts, this does not limit what characters can be displayed by the controls.

Comment: You've changed something somewhere. I don't see this behavior anywhere. Have you changed it in the form's font and left the form's controls ParentFont set to true (the default)?

Comment: no, i can open the project up, open any pas file with a dfm and all of them get changed automatically. Our software is currently running across multiple platforms and i'm not sure if it is possible to change this currently.

Comment: What Font is selected and what locale are the workstations set to?

Comment: Did you check the DFM itself to see if `ANSI_CHARSET` was stored in it?